# Forma de mapear un checkbox como bool (bit en SQL server)?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Se que siempre piden codigo, pero es basica mi pregunta. Tambien se que lo pueden calificar como "conocimiento general" o "respuesta subjetiva", pero aunque paresca increible, no hay muchos topicos en español que hablen del tema.

Basicamente tengo un HTML Helper Checkbox y quiero capturar su valor con AJAX/JSON y enviarlo a mi controller para que lo guarde en el modelo.

Ahora el problema es que no se como tratar al checkbox por que su valor pueder ser "on" o Nothing, cuando quiero capturar eso para llevarlo a la BD el modelo me exige que lo convierta en "true" o "false", asi que hago la conversion en el controller. Ahora lo interesante es que cuando veo la BD encuentro que los valores posibles (bit) pueden ser 0 o 1 y cuando hago el mapeo en vez de guardarme 1 (true) me guarda 0. Alguno sabe como debo "convertir" el dato para que lo considere como 1 o 0 en la BD? gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías adicionar estos input para controlar el valor que llega cuando se selecciona o no:

```
<form>
  <input type='hidden' value='0' name='selfdestruct'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='selfdestruct'>
</form>
```

Si es 1 lo conviertes a true en el modelo y si es cero a false.

Luego nuevamente a 1 y 0 en el sql.

Esta solución no es optima pero responde a tu pregunta, saludos

Comment: Ya encontre la forma, me puse a depurar el codigo con alertas y haciendo que grabe en otros campos de la BD. Es raro pero cuando estaba seleccionado el checkbox y en el controlador realizaba un request del elemento html me devolvia "true,false", si no estaba seleccionado me devolvia "false" luego con jquery tuve otros problemas, por alguna razon los metodos se llaman "attr()" y removeAttr()" cuando en otra pagina figuraban como  "setAttribute()" y "removeAttribute". Igual te dejo unos puntillos :)